I have POST and GET methods, but when I hide the get method why does an error occurs?(The post method should run until the page get dispatched to GET)
I am new to spring boot. I have get and post methods in my controller class.
But when I hide the get method I think the post method should run without an error until i hit submit. I have thyme leaf and spring-web dependencies.
when i use both post and get method it works fine.
singer.html page:
ENTER SINGER NAME
Enter Singer name

Enter Singer name

Enter Singer name

Songs.html page:
CHALEYA

HERIYE HERIYE

MUSKURANE KE WAJAH

PHIR BHI TUMKO CHAHUNGA

But when i comment out the get mapping method in the controller class I get an error:
Error
when I reload my localhost:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Sep 12 21:32:45 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

I get the following error in console:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]

Controller class: (GetMapping method commented out)
package com.aman.music.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.aman.music.Singers;

@Controller
public class MyController { 
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String home(@ModelAttribute Singers ss,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("this",ss);
        return "Songs" ;
    }
//  @GetMapping("/")
//  public String hii(Model model) {
//      model.addAttribute("this",new Singers());
//      return "singers";
//  }
}

These are my files:
MusicPlayerApplication.java
package com.aman.music;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MusicPlayerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MusicPlayerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Controller.java
package com.aman.music.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.aman.music.Singers;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String home(@ModelAttribute Singers ss,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("this",ss);
        return "Songs" ;
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hii(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("this",new Singers());
        return "singers";
    }   
}

Singers.java
package com.aman.music;
public class Singers {
    private String ArjitSingh;
    private String Singer;
    private String hello;

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }
    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
    public String getArjitSingh() {
        return ArjitSingh;
    }
    public void setArjitSingh(String arjitSingh) {
        ArjitSingh = arjitSingh;
    }
    public String getSinger() {
        return Singer;
    }
    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        Singer = singer;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Singers [ArjitSingh=" + ArjitSingh + ", Singer=" + Singer + ", hello=" + hello + "]";
    }   
}

Songs.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Songs List</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAdGW7QDJiU">CHALEYA</a>
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLzC55ai0eo">HERIYE HERIYE</a>
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ4Ox7mLqds">MUSKURANE KE WAJAH</a>
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iktURk0X-A">PHIR BHI TUMKO CHAHUNGA</a>
</body>
</html>

singers.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Singer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>ENTER SINGER NAME</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${this}" method="post">
    <p>Enter Singer name<input type="text" th:field="*{ArjitSingh}"/>
    <p>Enter Singer name<input type="text" th:field="*{Singer}"/>
    <p>Enter Singer name<input type="text" th:field="*{hello}"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
    </form>`

    </body>
    </html>

Kindly ignore the variables and file names i am using

GET and POST are two separate kinds of requests.  It sounds like you're removing the code which accepts a GET request, and then sending the server a GET request.  Which of course the server doesn't handle, because you told it not to.  Should this URL handle GET requests or not?

When you open a URL in the browser the HTTP method is always GET. Since you don't have any GET mapping in your application you get an error.
If you don't have a handler for error mapping (/error) you get White Label error on the browser.
You need GET mapping to load the singers.html file otherwise you will get error.

Thank you so much. It really helped in clearing my doubt.

Great to hear!!!
Please upvote and accept the answer. It helps me build my profile.
